# Irreducible characters of the direct product of two groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

I am studying representation and character theory because of my field of research. So, my question is not a homework.

I want to solve a problem of the book "character theory of finite groups" by M. Isaacs. The problem is as follows:

[image]

I know that if $A$ is an abelian group, then each character of $A$ in the field of complex numbers is linear. Also I know that if $G=H \times A$ then each irreducible character of $G$ can be written as $\phi \lambda$, where $\phi \in Irr(H)$ and $\lambda \in Irr(A)$. Using these facts, I tried to solve this problem but I could not find any useful ideas.

I will be so grateful for your helpful answers and comments.

Comment: What is $\chi^{(n)}$?

Comment: Hmm... perhaps my answer is wrong, I was assuming you meant $(g)\chi^{(n)} = (g^n)\chi$.

Comment: @Nate: No, you are right. I deleted my previous comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay here is an outline:

First reduce it to the case where $A$ is trivial, this can be done using the facts you mentioned.

Next note that $\chi$ is valued in $\mathbb{Q}[\zeta]$ where $\zeta$ is a primitive $|H|$th root of unity, and $\chi^{(n)}$ is just the image of $\chi$ under the field automorphism defined by $\zeta \to \zeta^n$ (which exists as $(|H|,n)=1$).

Then note that if $\chi$ is irreducible then $\langle\chi,\chi\rangle = \langle\chi^{(n)},\chi^{(n)}\rangle = 1$ since it is invariant under this field automorphism.

Now show that $\chi^{(n)}$ is in the $\mathbb{Z}$-span of the irreducible characters, as opposed to just the $\mathbb{C}$-span which we know a priori. One way to do this is to use the Newton identities for symmetric polynomials.

We can conclude that $\chi^{(n)}$ is $\pm1$ times an irreducible character.  To verify it is positive, try pairing it with the regular representation (the character of which is fixed by our field automorphism).

Comment: Thank you so much because of your answer. I don't understand why $\langle \chi^{(n)},\chi^{(n)}\rangle=1$. Also, would you please explain last two paragraphs more?

Comment: The point is that we know $\langle \chi^{(n)}, \chi^{(n)}\rangle$ is the image of $\langle \chi, \chi\rangle =1$ under this field automorphism, and $1$ is fixed under any field automorphism.

Comment: For the last two paragraphs I was alluding to the fact that the irreducible characters are a $\mathbb{C}$ basis for the space of class functions on $G$, which are orthonormal with respect to the form. Inside this space there are many vectors of norm $1$, but if we restrict to the lattice of integral virtual characters then there are only the irreducible characters and their negatives.

Comment: Thank you so much because of your helpful comments. I have just one more question. Is your proof based on considering $A$ as a trivial group or not? If this is true, I don't understand why your proof can work for every abelian group $A$, too.

Comment: Yes, my argument requires that we assume $A$ is trivial, because the characters might not be defined over this cyclotomic field otherwise. Here is the reduction to that case:  As you mentioned though irreducible characters of $H \times A$ are products $\chi \psi$ where $\chi$ is an irreducible $H$ character and $\psi$ is an $A$ character.  Now its easy to check that $(\chi \psi)^{(n)} = \chi^{(n)}\psi^{(n)}$  and $\psi^{(n)}=\psi^n$ is another irreducible character of $A$. So we just need to prove the claim for $\chi$ by itself, which corresponds to the $A$ trivial case.